# How do I remove duplicated string values when leveraging a TypeProvider?

Tags: f#

How do I remove duplicated string values when leveraging a TypeProvider?

**I have the following logic:**

```
type MovieProvider = JsonProvider<"https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json">

let getMovies() =

    async {
      let! result = MovieProvider.AsyncLoad "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json" 
      return result.Movies 
             |> Array.toList
             |> List.map (fun m -> { Title=m.Title; Year=m.ReleaseYear }) 
    }
```

**I would like to remove duplication of the hardcoded URL by doing the following:**

```
let url = "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json"

type MovieProvider = JsonProvider<url>

let getMovies() =

    async {
      let! result = MovieProvider.AsyncLoad url
      return result.Movies 
             |> Array.toList
             |> List.map (fun m -> { Title=m.Title; Year=m.ReleaseYear }) 
    }
```

**However, I receive the following error:**

```
type MovieProvider = JsonProvider<url>
```

> Error     This is not a valid constant expression or custom attribute
>   value

**Summary**

So what is the recommended practice in F# for managing duplication of hardcoded values?

In C#, I would just declare a constant.

Comment: For this particular purpose, use `MovieProvider.GetSample ()`. That's what it's there for.

Answer (score 6):

To declare a value literal as a compile-time constant in F#, use the `[<Literal>]` attribute.

```
[<Literal>]
let url = "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json"
```

or equivalently

```
let [<Literal>] url = "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json"
```